# How to add icon to text input field but keep background color as white?

Tags: html, css

I want to add an icon to an input field (a letter to an email input), the icon size is 22px by 22px, so I add padding to the left of the input field as 30px.  The page background is dark grey so I want the input field to be white to stand out. But if I add the icon it makes the rest of the input field transparant, how do I add the icon but keep the background color of the input field as white?.

```css
      body{
            background-color: darkgrey;
        }
        input{
            background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGEmz.png) no-repeat center left;
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
        }
```

```html
<input type="email"></input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the color to your background properties:

```css
background: #fff url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGEmz.png) no-repeat center left;
```

```css
body{
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
input{
  background: #fff url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGEmz.png) no-repeat center left;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="email"></input>
```